# Query a table based on ID

Tags: php, database

I am new to PHP and I would like to know how to query a table from a database based on an ID.

I am creating a search bar where users can search the database for employee details based on their ID (ID being the search query). The script would then retrieve the results from the table based on the ID.

Code:

```
    <form action="results.php" method="get">
        Employee ID: <input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php


// connect to the mysql database server
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=db_test14;charset=utf8', 'root', 'password');

// Prepare the statement (the basic outline of your query)
    $st = $db->prepare('SELECT * from techsols_employee WHERE id = ?');

// Actually execute the query, putting in your id
    $st->execute(array($employee_id));

// Get the actual employee details out of the result
    $employee = $st->fetch();
    ?>
```

Comment: For your needs the basic PHP functions should be enough. See: http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.mysql.php

Comment: A framework is a bunch of code pre-written which you can use as is. It is not magic and it's not something you can't do yourself.

Comment: Changed the topic of my question.

Answer (score 1):

> whether I would need to use a framework of some sort

No. The answer to that is always "no".

Frameworks can make some things easier because they have a bunch of code written for you already so you don't have to write it yourself.

Frameworks can make some things harder because they have a bunch of code written for you already and it might not quite work the way you need.

You can *always* write your own code from scratch.

(Whether or not that is a good idea depends on the context and is usually a matter of opinion).

Answer (score 1):

This can certainly be achieved with the inbuilt PHP functions. Despite what any tutorials you find online say, don't use any `mysql_*` functions - they're insecure and deprecated. Instead use [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

I'll give you an example. Suppose you have a table with the following columns:

```
id   employee_name   employee_address
```

You have a PHP variable with the employee id stored in it: `$employee_id`. Using the PDO you can get the employee's details like so:

```
// connect to the mysql database server
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

// Prepare the statement (the basic outline of your query)
$st = $db->prepare('SELECT * from employees WHERE id = ?');

// Actually execute the query, putting in your id
$st->execute(array($employee_id));

// Get the actual employee details out of the result
$employee = $st->fetch();
```

Prepared statements are useful with any data coming from unsanitised sources, i.e. from users, as they do filtering, etc to make sure that you don't risk SQL injections.

**UPDATE**:

Something like this *should* work, but it's untested. Basically have the form and the handler in the same file (not the best practice, but in this small example it's fine). If the form's been submitted, do the search and display some details. Otherwise show the form.

```
<?php

  //if the form's been sent, the "name" index will be in $_POST
  if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
      // connect to the mysql database server
          $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=db_test14;charset=utf8', 'root', 'password');
      
      // Prepare the statement (the basic outline of your query)
          $st = $db->prepare('SELECT * from techsols_employee WHERE id = ?');
      
      // Actually execute the query, putting in your id
          $st->execute(array($employee_id));
      
      // Get the actual employee details out of the result (as associative array)
          $employee = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          
          echo "Employee Details: " . $employee['name'] . ", " . $employee['address'];
  } else { 
    // otherwise, show the form
    // I've changed the action to the set it to the php file that shows the form.
  ?>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
        Employee ID: <input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit">
  </form>
<?php  } ?>
```

You could break this into two files: form.html and results.php, then have the PHP file redirect to form.html if nothing's been sent via post using the following instead of the form display code up there:

```
header('Location: form.html');
```

Comment: I see ok. I will write up a code and show it to you as I'm unsure how to link the search bar with the PHP script.

Comment: I've updated my question with my code. but im just stuck at the moment of linking the php script with the form.

Answer (score 0):

It finally comes down to how complex and what your needs are.
Frameworks are also php but built in such a way that will improve development speed with many of the day to day functions in built in them.
Since you mentioned to be a newbie in PHP I would recommend you first getting some regular php experience before jumping in to to frameworks as they tend to get complicated for a beginner.
Personally, I have found codeigniter to be more easy to learn from a newbie perspective.

However, your work can be done from basic php (by basic I mean normal php without use of a framework). It ultimately comes to how much you know in php, in frameworks, complexity of what you are doing etc.

Unfortunately there is no right answer. My recommendation is go with basic php since you are starting out. If you some how manage to get it up an running with a framework, you might actually not learn the actual php functionalities used in the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Basic functions will suffice, however that depends on your definition of "basic".

It depends on what database engine you're adopting. If it's Mongo, then [MongoClient](https://www.php.net/mongoclient), if it's MySql then [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo).

Remember to normalise your database!